# How can I reshape a tensor from `(None, a*b, None, ...)` to `(None, a, b, None, ...)` in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

Suppose I have a tensor named `t` having shape of `(None, a*b, None, ...)` (by ... I mean it has more dimentions but I don't care) and I want to reshape it to `(None, a, b, None, ...)`. What should I do?

I think I should get the shape of `t` by `tf.shape(t)` and then do something to it and after that I should use `tf.reshape()` to get my desired result. But what should I do in between?

Comment: you might need to split your tensor in several tensors, reshape them independently, and re-aggregate them

Comment: @DavidThery Thank you. But it would be great if there was a simpler way for this simple task